# REGISTRY issue in Visual Studio SETUP PROJECT

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, registry, setup-project, launch-condition

The installer will not proceed.

[image]

Comment: Please help me with the settings. I believe I did everything right but I may be missing something. Please see the IMAGE LINK above. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me! Please note the one and only comment in the article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2012/09/28/10354108.aspx

Not deleting the question in case other people encounter this problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a bug in VS launch conditions where it will not set the 64-bit search even if it's a 64-bit setup. If you use Orca to inspect the generated MSI file and look at the RegLocator table:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371171(v=vs.85).aspx

you'll see that the Type value hasn't set the msidbLocatorType64bit bit. The easiest detour is to set it with Orca while you're in there. Post-build scripts to update the value can be used to automatye this in a the build process.